# Is it possible to use if...else... statement in React render function?

Tags: reactjs

Basically, I have a react component, its `render()` function body is as below: (It is my ideal one, which means it currently does not work)

```js
render(){
    return (
        <div>
            <Element1/>
            <Element2/>

            // note: logic only, code does not work here
            if (this.props.hasImage) <ElementWithImage/>
            else <ElementWithoutImage/>

        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Yeah this is a very common issue to run into and a great question! Maybe wording it a little different and showing what happens you run this particular code (also consider formatting it a bit) would help clear up exactly the issue.

Comment: Yes, it is a wrong one (ideal one). I have just updated the question to clear the issue. Thanks

Comment: official documentation:  https://react.dev/learn/conditional-rendering

Answer (score 493, accepted):

Not exactly like that, but there are workarounds. There's a section in [React's docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) about conditional rendering that you should take a look. Here's an example of what you could do using inline if-else.

```
render() {
  const isLoggedIn = this.state.isLoggedIn;
  return (
    <div>
      {isLoggedIn ? (
        <LogoutButton onClick={this.handleLogoutClick} />
      ) : (
        <LoginButton onClick={this.handleLoginClick} />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can also deal with it inside the render function, but before returning the jsx.

```
if (isLoggedIn) {
  button = <LogoutButton onClick={this.handleLogoutClick} />;
} else {
  button = <LoginButton onClick={this.handleLoginClick} />;
}

return (
  <div>
    <Greeting isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn} />
    {button}
  </div>
);
```

It's also worth mentioning what ZekeDroid brought up in the comments. If you're just checking for a condition and don't want to render a particular piece of code that doesn't comply, you can use the `&& operator`.

```
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello!</h1>
      {unreadMessages.length > 0 &&
        <h2>
          You have {unreadMessages.length} unread messages.
        </h2>
      }
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: A nifty trick is also using the short circuit feature of JS! To avoid doing something like `isTrue ? <div>Something</div> : null` you can just do `isTrue && <div>Something</div>`

Comment: In addition, you can checkout the following article to find out about more [conditional renderings in React](https://www.robinwieruch.de/conditional-rendering-react/) apart from if else.

Comment: I want to handle condition in the loop like
"data.map(item => (
<tr>
   <td>
     if(item.type == 'image'){
    <image src="{image.src}">
    } else{
       { item}
  }
  </td>

</tr>

))
"

something like this

Comment: why did they do it this way?  Why rewrite javascript?  I was taught in programming 101 to not use ternary operators, when I can use 'if'.  One is much more readable.

Answer (score 202):

There actually is a way to do exactly what OP is asking. Just render and call an anonymous function like so:

```
render () {
  return (
    <div>
      {(() => {
        if (someCase) {
          return (
            <div>someCase</div>
          )
        } else if (otherCase) {
          return (
            <div>otherCase</div>
          )
        } else {
          return (
            <div>catch all</div>
          )
        }
      })()}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Answer is really nice. Just makes me ask the question about React in general, why it is like early days of PHP?

Answer (score 50):

### Four ways of conditional rendering

(In functional component's return statement or class component's render function's return statement)

#### Ternary operator

```
return (
    <div>     
        {
            'a'==='a' ? <p>Hi</p> : <p>Bye</p>
        } 
    </div>
)
```

> **Note:** Only if the condition `'a'==='a'` is true,  `<p>Hi</p>` will be rendered in the screen. Otherwise,  `<p>Bye</p>`  will be rendered on the screen.

#### Logical operator

**AND `&&`**

```
return (
    <div>     
        {
            'a'==='a' && <p>Hi</p>
        } 
    </div>
)
```

> **Note:** Only if the condition `'a'==='a'` is true,  `<p>Hi</p>` will be rendered in the screen.

**OR `||`**

```
export default function LogicalOperatorExample({name, labelText}) {
    
  return (
    <div>       
         {labelText || name}      
    </div>
  )
}
```

> **Note:** If  `labelText` and `name` both props are passed into this component, then `labelText` will be rendered in the screen. But if only one of them (`name` or `labelText` ) is passed  as prop, then that passed prop will be rendered in the screen.

#### if, else, else if

```
return ( 
        <div>     
            {
                (() => {
                    if('a'==='b') {
                            return (
                                <p>Hi</p>
                            )
                        } else if ('b'==='b') {
                            return (
                            <p>Hello</p>
                            )
                        } else {
                            return (
                                <p>Bye</p>
                            )
                        }
                })()  
            }  
        </div>  
    )
```

> **Note:** Have to use an anonymous functions (also need to immediately invoke the function )

#### Switch statement

```
return ( 
    <div>     
        {
            (() => {
                switch(true) {
                        
                    case('a'==='b'): {
                            return (
                                <p>Hello</p>
                            )
                        }
                    break;
                        
                    case('a'==='a'): {
                        return (
                            <p>Hi</p>
                        )
                    }
                    break;
                    
                    default: {
                            return (
                                <p>Bye</p>
                            )
                        }
                    break;
                    }
            })()  
        }  
    </div>  
)
```

> **Note:** Have to use an anonymous functions (also need to immediately invoke the function)

Comment: which is better for performance switch or if elseif

Comment: The performance difference between them is negligible, the choice between them often comes down to personal preference and readability.

Comment: I find your response very helpful as you showed us lots of different ways. Thanks for your contribution.

Answer (score 20):

You can render anything using the `conditional` statement like `if`, `else` :

```
 render() {
    const price = this.state.price;
    let comp;

    if (price) {

      comp = <h1>Block for getting started with {this.state.price}</h1>

    } else {

      comp = <h1>Block for getting started.</h1>

    }

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="gettingStart">
          {comp}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 20):

**For only if:**

```
{condition1 && 
(<div> condition1 true </div>)}
```

**For if and else:**

```
{condition1 ? 
(<div> condition1 true </div>)
:(<div> condition1 false </div>)}
```

**For if, else if, and else:**

```
{condition1 ? 
(<div>condition1 true</div>)
:(condition2) ? 
(<div>condition2 true</div>)
:(<div>both conditions false</div>)}
```

Answer (score 17):

**Type 1:** `If` statement style

```
{props.hasImage &&

  <MyImage />

}
```

**Type 2:** `If else` statement style

```
   {props.hasImage ?

      <MyImage /> :

      <OtherElement/>

    }
```

Answer (score 6):

The shorthand for an if else structure works as expected in JSX

`this.props.hasImage ? <MyImage /> : <SomeotherElement>`

You can find other options on this blogpost of [DevNacho](http://devnacho.com/2016/02/15/different-ways-to-add-if-else-statements-in-JSX/), but it's more common to do it with the shorthand. If you need to have a bigger if clause you should write a function that returns **or** component A **or** component B.

for example:

```
this.setState({overlayHovered: true});

renderComponentByState({overlayHovered}){
    if(overlayHovered) {
        return <OverlayHoveredComponent />
    }else{
        return <OverlayNotHoveredComponent />
    }
}
```

You can destructure your overlayHovered from this.state if you give it as parameter. Then execute that function in your render() method:

`renderComponentByState(this.state)`

Answer (score 6):

You should Remember about **TERNARY operator**

> **:**

so your code will  be like this,

```
render(){
    return (
        <div>
            <Element1/>
            <Element2/>
            // note: code does not work here
            { 
               this.props.hasImage ?  // if has image
               <MyImage />            // return My image tag 
               :
               <OtherElement/>        // otherwise return other element  

             }
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you need more than one condition, so you can try this out

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-if-elseif-else-render

```
import { If, Then, ElseIf, Else } from 'react-if-elseif-else-render';

class Example extends Component {

  render() {
    var i = 3; // it will render '<p>Else</p>'
    return (
      <If condition={i == 1}>
        <Then>
          <p>Then: 1</p>
        </Then>
        <ElseIf condition={i == 2}>
          <p>ElseIf: 2</p>
        </ElseIf>
        <Else>
          <p>Else</p>
        </Else>
      </If>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also use conditional (ternary) operator inside conditional operator in case you have 2 different dependencies.

```
{
(launch_success)
  ?
  <span className="bg-green-100">
    Success
  </span>
  :
  (upcoming)
    ?
    <span className="bg-teal-100">
      Upcoming
    </span>
    :
    <span className="bg-red-100">
      Failed
    </span>
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want a condition to show elements, you can use something like this.

```
renderButton() {
    if (this.state.loading) {
        return <Spinner size="small" spinnerStyle={styles.spinnerStyle} />;
    }

    return (
        <Button onPress={this.onButtonPress.bind(this)}>
            Log In
        </Button>
    );
}
```

Then call the helping method inside render function.

```
<View style={styles.buttonStyle}>
      {this.renderButton()}
</View>
```

Or you can use another way of condition inside return.

```
{this.props.hasImage ? <element1> : <element2>}
```

Answer (score 3):

I used a ternary operator and it's working fine for me.

```
{item.lotNum == null ? ('PDF'):(item.lotNum)}
```

Comment: Unexpected token, expected "," ....for ternary operator based conditioning

Answer (score 3):

Lot's of great answers, however I haven't seen the use of an object for mapping to different views

```
const LOGS = {
  info: <Info />,
  warning: <Warning />,
  error: <Error />,
};
 
const Notification = ({ status }) => <div>{LOGS[status]}</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

None of the answers mention the short-circuit method

```js
{this.props.hasImage && <MyImage />}
```

Granted you cannot use it if you want to render something on the else logic.
I learned about this on [react by example](https://reactbyexample.github.io/about-jsx)

on a deeper scan I do see a comment by @ZekeDroid, but I will drop this as an answer since it could be useful.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can use condition in JSX render. You can read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

**Syntax:**

```
condition ? exprIfTrue : exprIfFalse
```

Condition statement must be this way below, here an example:

```
return (
    <div>
      {condition  ? (
        //do some actions if condition is true
      ) : (
        //do some actions if condition is false
      )}
    </div>
)
```

Answer (score 2):

May be I'm too late here. But I hope this would help someone. First separate those two elements.

```
renderLogout(){
<div>
   <LogoutButton onClick={this.handleLogoutClick} />
<div>
}

renderLogin(){
<div>
   <LoginButton onClick={this.handleLoginClick} />
<div>
}
```

Then you can call these functions from render function using if else statement.

```
render(){
if(this.state.result){
  return this.renderResult();
}else{
  return this.renderQuiz();
}}
```

This works for me. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try going with Switch case or ternary operator

```sh
render(){
    return (
        <div>
            <Element1/>
            <Element2/>
            // updated code works here
            {(() => {
                        switch (this.props.hasImage) {
                            case (this.props.hasImage):
                                return <MyImage />;
                            default:
                                return (
                                   <OtherElement/>; 
                                );
                        }
                    })()}
        </div>
    )
}
```

This worked for me and should work for you else.
Try [Ternary Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use If, else if, and else then use this method

```
           {this.state.value === 0 ? (
                <Component1 />
            ) : this.state.value === 1 ? (
              <Component2 />
            ) : (
              <Component3 />
            )}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can introduce separate method that will return div elements and call it inside of return. I use this case for example for error rendering depends on status, such as:

```
const renderError = () => {
    if (condition)
        return ....;
    else if (condition)
        return ....;
    else if (condition)
        return ....;
    else
        return ....;
}

render(){
   return (
     <div>
      ....
      {renderError()}
     </div>
   );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Shorthand for if then

```
 { condition ? <Element1/> : null }
```

Comment: {condition && <Element1/>} do the same and it's more cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think i saw this solution for an inline else if rendering where you have more that 2 conditions so i'm sharing it :

```
{variable == 0 ?
  <Element1/>
:variable == 1 ?
  <Element2/>
:variable == 2 ?
  <Element3/>
:
  <Element4/>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that a solution that I thought was better than having an if-else. Instead have 2 return statements. See example:

```
render() {
    const isLoggedIn = this.state.isLoggedIn;

    if (isLoggedIn) {
        return <LogoutButton onClick={this.handleLogoutClick} />
    }

    // This will never occur if the user is logged in as the function is returned before that.
    return <LoginButton onClick={this.handleLoginClick} />
}
```

This is less cluttered than having an if-else or ternary operator in your return statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can write If statement component too. Here is what I use in my project.

components/IfStatement.tsx

```
import React from 'react'

const defaultProps = {
    condition: undefined,
}

interface IfProps {
    children: React.ReactNode
    condition: any
}

interface StaticComponents {
    Then: React.FC<{ children: any }>
    Else: React.FC<{ children: any }>
}

export function If({ children, condition }: IfProps): any & StaticComponents {
    if (React.Children.count(children) === 1) {
        return condition ? children : null
    }

    return React.Children.map(children as any, (element: React.ReactElement) => {
        const { type: Component }: any = element

        if (condition) {
            if (Component.type === 'then') {
                return element
            }
        } else if (Component.type === 'else') {
            return element
        }

        return null
    })
}

If.defaultProps = defaultProps

export function Then({ children }: { children: any }) {
    return children
}

Then.type = 'then'

export function Else({ children }: { children: any }) {
    return children
}

Else.type = 'else'

If.Then = Then as React.FC<{ children: any }>
If.Else = Else as React.FC<{ children: any }>

export default If
```

Usage example:

```
<If condition={true}>
   <If.Then>
        <div>TRUE</div>
   </If.Then>
   <If.Else>
        <div>NOT TRUE</div>
   </If.Else>
</If>
```

Answer (score -1):

Below Code you can use for If condition on react in side return

```
                                    {(() => {if (true) {return ( <div><Form>
                                        <Form.Group as={Row} style={{ marginLeft: '15px', marginRight: '15px', marginBlock: '0px' }} >
                                            <Form.Label className="summary-smmdfont" style={{ flex: '1 0 auto', marginBlock: '0px' }}>   uyt</Form.Label>
                                            <Form.Label className="summary-smmdfont"style={{ textAlignLast: 'Right', flex: '1 0 auto', marginBlock: '0px' }}>
                                                09</Form.Label>
                                        </Form.Group>
                                        </Form>

                                    </div>);
                    }})()}
```