# Constructing HTML with IF ELSE

Tags: reactjs

Hi I am trying to create HTML inside render where some of the portion is dependent on a condition which I am putting in IF ELSE. But if statement is been treated as plain text and not getting result as expected. Can someone tell me where am I wrong?

```
render(){
    console.log('email'+this.state.email);

    var html =  <Navbar style={styles.menu} color="faded" light expand="md">
        <NavbarBrand style={styles.image} href="/"><img  src="../../images/op-logo.jpg"/></NavbarBrand>
        <NavbarToggler onClick={this.toggle} />
        <Collapse isOpen={this.state.isOpen} navbar>
          <Nav className="ml-auto" navbar>
            <NavItem>
              <NavLink href="/tournaments">Tournaments</NavLink>
            </NavItem>
            <NavItem>
              <NavLink href="/players-ladder">Ladder</NavLink>
            </NavItem>
            if (this.state.email!='') {
              ('Welcome' + this.state.email+<NavItem><NavLink href="/logout">Logout</NavLink></NavItem>)
            } else {
              (<NavItem><NavLink href="/login">Login/Signup</NavLink></NavItem>)
            }
          </Nav>
        </Collapse>
      </Navbar>

    return (
      <div>
        {html}
      </div>);
  }
```

Comment: It's because you're trying to write a condition inside JSX. Move it out and render the conditional html as "normal".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use if...else... statement in React render function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40477245/is-it-possible-to-use-if-else-statement-in-react-render-function)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside of `jsx` you can't use an `if` block because `jsx` gets parsed and transpiled to javascript and its syntax does not allow for it. But you can use the [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) in most cases to do conditional rendering:

```
{this.state.email ? (
    <React.Fragment>
        <p>{`Welcome ${this.state.email}`}</p>
        <NavItem>
            <NavLink href="/logout">Logout</NavLink>
        </NavItem>
    </React.Fragment>
) : (
    <NavItem>
        <NavLink href="/login">Login/Signup</NavLink>
    </NavItem>
)}
```

Also note that you do **not** create html inside the render method. `jsx` gets fully transpiled to javascript. You can consider it to be an embedded template language with includes and partials in the form of react components with react being the rendering engine.

Comment: getting this error  Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag (63:6)

  61 |             {this.state.email ? (
  62 |       <p>{`Welcome ${this.state.email}`}</p>
> 63 |       <NavItem>
     |       ^

Comment: @hitesh See my updated answer. It's because the `<p>` and `<NavItem>` are on the same level and need to be wrapped into a containing element. You can use the `<Fragment>` container for that.