# If-statement in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

I have written an if-statement which is meant to return a certain color depending on two boolean variables (active and acknowledged). However, having a background in Java and being new to ReactJs and JSX, I found this task more difficult than what I feel is needed. *This if-statement only returns the color orange*. I can't understand how the &&-operator works.

**The goal:** if active and acknowledged both are true, I want to set the icon to an orange color. If active is true but acknowledged is false, I want to set the icon to a red color. If active is false but acknowledged is true, I want to set the icon to a green color. If both active and acknowledged is false, then the icon will be grey.

Here's my code:

```
//Mapping Json-object 
const active = data.Status.map(status => status.active);
const acknowledged = data.Status.map(status => status.acknowledged);

//Method called from component 
function bellStatus() {
    if(active && acknowledged) {
        return {color: "#ff893d", marginRight: "10px"} //orange
    }else if(active && !acknowledged) {       
        return {color: "#fe4242", marginRight: "10px"} //red
    }else if(!active && acknowledged) {
        return {color: "#5ab65a", marginRight: "10px"} //green
    }else {
        return {color: "#acacac", marginRight: "10px"} //grey
    }
}

//Component in return
<FontAwesomeIcon icon="bell" style={bellStatus()} />

//Json
{
  "id": "1",
  "Status": [{
      "active": true,
      "acknowledged": false
   }]
},
{
  "id": "2",
  "Status": [{
      "active": false,
      "acknowledged": false
  }]
},
{
  "id": "3",
  "Status": [{
      "active": true,
      "acknowledged": false
  }]
}
```

Why am I running into this problem and how would this 'translate' into JSX/ES6? The variables are showing the correct values, but the if-statement is obviously wrong.

Comment: Can you post the full code?

Comment: `&&` means if both the operands are `true` only then it will be `true`. If it's returning color orange, that means both `active` and `acknowledged` are `true`. Full code will certainly help.

Comment: refer this link, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40477245/is-it-possible-to-use-if-else-statement-in-react-render-function

Comment: map returns a list of booleans

Comment: @IshanJoshi I know it does ... that's not the issue here. The issue is the syntax.

Comment: so if active will evaluate to true if all are true? Is that what you were trying to acheive

Comment: No, if active and acknowledged both are true, i want to set the icon to an orange color. If active is true but acknowledged is false, i want to set the icon to a red color. If active is false but acknowledged is true, i want to set the icon to a green color. if both active and acknowledged is false, i want to set the icon to a grey color.

Comment: Are you rendering an icon for each item in the json data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is Map returns an array and so both your active and acknowledge are arrays as such the check `active && acknowledge` are always true as they are arrays and exist that's why you are getting just the result of the first case. you can verify that by logging the value of active as well as acknowledge. So basically there is nothing wrong with your comparison with `ifs` but rather with what you are using to compare. You can read more about map here [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Aaah ... that makes way more sense! I'll read into it. Thanks!

Comment: you could change your json data like this {
  "id": "1",
  "Status": {
      "active": true,
      "acknowledged": false
   }
} then you won't have to map but rather just do data.Status.active && data.Status.acknowlege in your check