# React Component : "if else" statement not updating inside return statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, react-component

I am noob in React and pretty new in front.

I am trying to change the color of the property "fill" (in polygon) in React. 
If perc > 50 i want the result to be green, and otherwise red.

I have written an "if else" statement but no color is rendering.

I have checked this [Is it possible to use if...else... statement in React render function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40477245/is-it-possible-to-use-if-else-statement-in-react-render-function) and other sources online/ What i want to do seems possible and i don't know why its not rendering.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class SvgStationIconGauge extends Component {
  render() {
    const { perc } = this.props || 0;
    const color_fill = 0;
    if (perc >50) {
      color_fill = "#ff0000";
    } else {
      color_fill = "#00ff00";
    }
    return (
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 50 120" className="icon-station">
        <title>Station name</title>
        <desc>Marker with gauge to display availability </desc>
     //#Here is what i am trying to render!!
        <polygon points="2 2 48 2 48 80 25 118 2 80" stroke="#333333" strokeWidth="4" fill= {color_fill} />
        <clipPath id="fill-icon">
          <polygon points="4 4 46 4 46 80 25 116 4 80 " strokeWidth="1" />
        </clipPath>
        <g clipPath="url(#fill-icon)">
          <rect width="100%" height={perc} fill="white" />
        </g>
      </svg>
    );
  }
}

export default SvgStationIconGauge;
```

As mentionned, i am a noob in React and any observation or suggestion would be welcomed!

Comment: Use ```const { perc = 0 } = this.props ;``` instead of ```const { perc } = this.props || 0;```

Comment: Use `const color_fill = perc > 50 ? "#ff0000" : "#00ff00"` instead of `if`

Comment: Change ```const fill_color```  to ```let fill_color```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't ressign `const`. use `let`

```
let color_fill = 0;
    if (perc >50) {
      color_fill = "#ff0000";
    } else {
      color_fill = "#00ff00";
    }
```

Comment: anyways, `vscode` or any editor will throw compile time error

Answer (score 1):

You can't reassign a `const` value. Either make `colour_fill` a `let` or try:

`const color_fill = perc >50 ? "#ff0000" : "#00ff00";`