# why I am getting parsing error in my else part?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7r7MT.png)

I am trying it for a long time but always there is a compile time error

Comment: you might be conflicting with the jsx syntax. Try using the ternary operator `?`

Comment: Can you write the code here, it is much easier

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to use if...else... statement in React render function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40477245/is-it-possible-to-use-if-else-statement-in-react-render-function)

Answer (score 1):

Because that is not a valid syntax in JSX.

See: https://react-cn.github.io/react/tips/if-else-in-JSX.html

> `if-else` statements don't work inside JSX. This is because JSX is just syntactic sugar for function calls and object construction.

Use ternary or variable assignments instead.

Answer (score 0):

@Chase is right. JSX does not support if-else. Instead you should use ternary operator. I modified your code. Please check it below:

```
const App = () => {
    const [show, setShow] = useState();
    show.map(show => {
        return (
            (show) ?
                <div>
                    <h1 className="design">
                        <Counter/>
                    </h1>
                    <User/>
                </div>
                :
                <div>
                    <h2 className="design2">
                        <Counter/>
                    </h2>
                </div>
        )
    })
};
```