# What's the correct syntax for if conditional when working with calling components in React + Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx, tsx

I'm currently trying to display a component and pass in a function as a prop only if one of its state properties is true. However, I'm having trouble with the syntax. Here's what I have:

```
render = () => {
return (
  <ParentComponent>

       {if (this.onlyRenderIfTrue) {
          <ChildComponent prop1={this.usefulFunction()}/>
       }}

  </ParentComponent>
);
```

}

The JSX is a bit confusing for me. I know anytime I have to use Javascript I have to put it in {}, but for something a bit more nested like this, it's throwing me off a bit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to use if...else... statement in React render function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40477245/is-it-possible-to-use-if-else-statement-in-react-render-function)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write conditional statement directly in React render hook. You may use `&&` operator or `ternary` operator however:

```
render = () => {
  return (
   <ParentComponent>
   {
      this.onlyRenderIfTrue &&
      <ChildComponent prop1={this.usefulFunction()}/>
   }
   </ParentComponent>
  );
}
```

If you wish to use conditional statement, then you may define a function like:

```
const renderComponent = () => {
  if (somethingIsTrue) {
   return <h1>True</h1>
  } else {
   return <p>False</p>
  }
}
```

Now, inside your component render, you can call:

```
{renderComponent()}
```

Comment: Probably just a mistake but you missed the `{}` part around `this.onlyRenderIfTrue &&`.