# Using if else in reactjs render

Tags: reactjs, if-statement

How can I use if else inside div tags?

I want a use like here. So if customer.info is empty or -1 then it shows the code below, if not it doesn't show it

I made a few tries but couldn't.

```
 if (this.props.customerInfo.customer === "-1") {
  <TableEditColumn
                showAddCommand
                showEditCommand
                showDeleteCommand
                commandComponent={Command}
              />
 }



render() {
    if (!isLoaded) {
      return <div>Loading</div>;
    } else {
      return (
        <div>
          <Paper>
            <Grid
              rows={this.state.treatmentItems}
              columns={this.state.columns}
            >
              <EditingState
                onCommitChanges={this.commitChanges}
              />

              <Table />
              <TableColumnResizing
                defaultColumnWidths={this.state.defaultColumnWidths}
              />
             
              <TableEditRow />
              <TableEditColumn
                showAddCommand
                showEditCommand
                showDeleteCommand
                commandComponent={Command}
              />
            </Grid>
          </Paper>

        </div>
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to use if...else... statement in React render function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40477245/is-it-possible-to-use-if-else-statement-in-react-render-function)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use conditional rendering, "?" means true ":" means false u can also use "&&" for one condition

```
    render() {
          return (
{isLoaded ?
            <div>
              <Paper>
                <Grid
                  rows={this.state.treatmentItems}
                  columns={this.state.columns}
                >
                  <EditingState
                    onCommitChanges={this.commitChanges}
                  />
    
                  <Table />
                  <TableColumnResizing
                    defaultColumnWidths={this.state.defaultColumnWidths}
                  />
                 
                  <TableEditRow />
                  <TableEditColumn
                    showAddCommand
                    showEditCommand
                    showDeleteCommand
                    commandComponent={Command}
                  />
                </Grid>
              </Paper>
    
            </div> 
: <p> Loading... <p/>}
          );
        }
      }
```

Comment: I want this Let (this.props.customerInfo.customer === null) show the code I chose.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to understand what you're asking, but here is what I think you're looking for:

You have three options to conditionally render from within JSX. You cannot use an `if...else` directly inside a JSX expression. Instead, here are your options:

1. Use a ternary.

```js
<Paper>
  <Grid
    rows={this.state.treatmentItems}
    columns={this.state.columns}
  >
    <EditingState
      onCommitChanges={this.commitChanges}
    />
    <Table />
    <TableColumnResizing
      defaultColumnWidths={this.state.defaultColumnWidths}
    />
    <TableEditRow />
    {this.props.customerInfo.customer === null ? // If the expression is true, render this
      <TableEditColumn
        showAddCommand
        showEditCommand
        showDeleteCommand
        commandComponent={Command}
      />
    : null} // if the expression is false render `null`
  </Grid>
</Paper>
```

2. Use a short circuit pattern

```js
<Paper>
  <Grid
    rows={this.state.treatmentItems}
    columns={this.state.columns}
  >
    <EditingState
      onCommitChanges={this.commitChanges}
    />
    <Table />
    <TableColumnResizing
      defaultColumnWidths={this.state.defaultColumnWidths}
    />
    <TableEditRow />
    {this.props.customerInfo.customer === null && // If expression is true render this
      <TableEditColumn
        showAddCommand
        showEditCommand
        showDeleteCommand
        commandComponent={Command}
      />
    }
  </Grid>
</Paper>
```

3. Move the logic into a separate function and use `if...else`.

```js
renderEdit = () => {
  // We are outside of JSX so we can now use any JavaScript conditional operators we like
  if (this.props.customerInfo.customer === null) {
    return (
      <TableEditColumn
        showAddCommand
        showEditCommand
        showDeleteCommand
        commandComponent={Command}
      />
    );
  }
  return null;
}

<Paper>
  <Grid
    rows={this.state.treatmentItems}
    columns={this.state.columns}
  >
    <EditingState
      onCommitChanges={this.commitChanges}
    />
    <Table />
    <TableColumnResizing
      defaultColumnWidths={this.state.defaultColumnWidths}
    />
    <TableEditRow />
    {renderEdit()}
  </Grid>
</Paper>
```

You can read more in-depth [here in the docs for conditional rendering in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html).