# How do I render an element within mongoose query in .jsx file?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

```
<aside className="col-2">
    {( () => {
        Bike.find({}, (error, data) => {
           data.map((bike) => 
             <h4>{bike.name}</h4>
            )
        })
     }
     )()}
</aside>
```

I'm making an aside in a Layout.jsx file. In it, I've required a models folder which uses mongoose to query data in mongoDB. Before, to run a function inside a .jsx file, I've used code modelled after a solution to a question posted here:
[Is it possible to use if...else... statement in React render function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40477245/is-it-possible-to-use-if-else-statement-in-react-render-function)
In my code above I've consoled.log(data.name) inside the map function to check that I'm getting the data that I'm looking for. Indeed, I've queried the right data. However, I can't render that data as an h4 tag.

Comment: Are you also using React?

Comment: @Anuga - Yup, I'm using react