# React: conditionally render an item in the menu

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-functional-component, conditional-rendering

I'm using React with Material-UI.
I'm developing a simple UI in a form of a dropdown menu. I'd like to control the rendering of the first row with condition passed as a prop. How can I use the condition to render or skip rendering of the first row?

```
export const NativeSdkMenu = memo(({ showFirstMenuItem }) => (
  <Menu>
    <MenuItem component="a" href={link1}>
      {"First"}
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem component="a" href={link1}>
      {"Second"}
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem component="a" href={link1}>
      {"Third"}
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem component="a" href={link1}>
      {"Fourth"}
    </MenuItem>
  </Menu>
));
```

Obviously this doesn't work:

```
if (showFirstMenuItem) {
    <MenuItem component="a" href={link1}>
      {"First"}
    </MenuItem>
}
```

I've tried a few similar approaches, but it looks like I need to use some specific JSX syntax which I don't know.

Comment: Please show your attempt. We'll be happy to show you where it went wrong, or a better alternative. If there has been no attempt, please read the section of the docs on [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html), specifically the section on [inline conditions](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator).

Comment: Added....................

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to use if...else... statement in React render function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40477245/is-it-possible-to-use-if-else-statement-in-react-render-function)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your sample and assuming your prop showFirstMenuItem is a boolean you can simply use the && operator to show the first item if your  showFirstMenuItem is true:

```
export const NativeSdkMenu = memo(({ showFirstMenuItem }) => (
 <Menu>
  {showFirstMenuItem && (
    <MenuItem component="a" href={link1}>
      {"First"}
   </MenuItem>)}
   <MenuItem component="a" href={link1}>
    {"Second"}
   </MenuItem>
   <MenuItem component="a" href={link1}>
     {"Third"}
   </MenuItem>
   <MenuItem component="a" href={link1}>
    {"Fourth"}
   </MenuItem>
  </Menu>
  ));
```

Comment: Excellent solution. Enclosing the whole menuitem into parenthesis `()` was the root cause of the few of my approaches not working.

Comment: You're welcome, you can take a look on this article to see some other approaches for conditional rendering: https://www.robinwieruch.de/conditional-rendering-react

Comment: Thanks, I've seen that article actually before trying few of my approaches...

Answer (score 2):

Quite simple actually

```
export const NativeSdkMenu = memo(({ showFirstMenuItem }) => (
  <Menu>
   {showFirstMenuItem && <MenuItem component="a" href={link1}>
   {"First"}
  </MenuItem>}
  <MenuItem component="a" href={link1}>
   {"Second"}
  </MenuItem>
  <MenuItem component="a" href={link1}>
   {"Third"}
  </MenuItem>
  <MenuItem component="a" href={link1}>
   {"Fourth"}
  </MenuItem>
</Menu>
));
```

Comment: Good direction, but also I had to add `(` and `)` around the whole `MenuItem` to make it compile.

Answer (score 1):

You can set css class conditionnally with your prop value :

```
<MenuItem component="a" href={link1} className={this.props.showFirstMenuItem ? style['your-class-name'] : ''}>
  {"First"}
</MenuItem>
```

Comment: I'd prefer react-based solution, so that I won't have to modify styles / create classes, but thanks for the help!

Comment: Srry I missread i thought u want to render in a different way and not just show / hide !!

Comment: No problem. I wanted just to hide/show the first (or any other item) in the menu by controlling it with a prop that passed externally.