# React: the (??) shorthand not working for JSX conditional checks?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

The ?? shorthand never seems to work for me? so I end up having to write a ternary operator with a useless opperand?

Below code works properly:

```
(object.array.length > 0 ? (<div>Yes</div>) : (<div></div>))
```

But this one does not:

```
object.array.length > 0 ?? (<div>Yes</div>)
```

Comment: Please read [how `??` works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator). I think you have a misunderstanding.

Comment: The ?? operator is used in conjunction with array.length here, no? https://stackoverflow.com/a/40477289/14357749 - Is this answer wrong?

Comment: `??` does not work with booleans, it works with nullish values. Since neither `true` or `false` are nullish, that second code example will never be that div code, because that's what you wrote it to do. Read the article about `??` that 0strone0 linked to.

Comment: Have you tried reading the docs? The "nullish coalescing" operator only comes into action, when the first expression is `null` or `undefined`, hence the name. In your case the first expression is a boolean, thus *never* `null`or `undefined`

Comment: In which of the answers exactly do you see a `??` Note, there is a difference between `?` and `??` The answer you linked to uses `array.length && ...` which is again a totally different operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments above, what you're looking for is simply `&&`:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      {object.array.length > 0 && (
        <div>Yes</div>
      )}
    </Fragment>
  )
}
```

Comment: You've just copied my evaluation, which I said didn't work?

Comment: No? I used `&&` and you used `??`. Double ampersand vs double question mark. @user231071

Answer (score 0):

Note that `??` also known as `nullish coalescing operator` simply returns the expression on the right side of the mark when the expression on the left side is `null` or `undefined`.

That said, I think there's a problem with the approach you are trying to use,

1 -  object.array.length > 0 ?? (Yes)
If `object` or `array on object` ever comes as undefined, you'll have a reference issues and your app/component may crash, throwing errors like `cannot read array or length of undefined`

To fix that, you could use optional chaining and do something like:
`object?.array?.length ?? (<div>Yes</div>)`

You won't have reference issues and all, i.e you'll have the right side rendered if either `object or array` were `undefined/null`

But, do you really want to render `object?.array?.length > 0` when all references are good? I don't think you'll have desired results.

2- Suggested solution by **emeraldsanto** is good, however, going back to problem 1, lest you trust you'll always have `object & array`, you can safely use **emeraldsanto** solution,

otherwise, I'd recommend this as a safer solution.

```
<Fragment>
    {someVar?.box?.length > 0 ? <div>Yes</div> : null }
</Fragment>
```