# If-else inside array of objects using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of objects where I define multiple icons that needs to be displayed.

```
const iconButtonList = [
        {
            icon: <AddIcon />,
            onClick: onClickOpenRuleEditor,
            isDisabled: false,
            label:"Add"
        },
        {
            icon: <EditIcon />,
            onClick: onClickOpenRuleEditor,
            isDisabled: isEditDisabled
        },
        {
            icon: <CopyIcon />,
            onClick: onClickCopyRules,
            isDisabled: true
        },
        {
            icon: <TrashIcon />,
            onClick: onDelete,
            isDisabled: isRemoveDisabled
        },
        {
            icon: <RefreshIcon />,
            onClick: onClickRefreshRulesGrid,
            isDisabled: false
        }];
```

I loop through through the array and display all the icons within a div element.

```
const gridActionButtons =
        <div>
            {
                iconButtonList.map((element, index) => (
                  <IconButton
                    key={index}
                    flat
                    secondary
                    label={element.label}
                    icon={element.icon}
                    isDisabled={element.isDisabled}
                    onClick={element.onClick}/>)
                )
            }
</div>;
```

In addition to the icons defined, I would like to display few other icons based on the tab selected, for which I would like to add if-else within the array. I tried to do something like this:

```
{
            icon: <RefreshIcon />,
            onClick: onClickRefreshRulesGrid,
            isDisabled: false
        },
        {
            if: {
                selectedTab:0
            },then :[{
                    icon: `<DeploymentIcon />`,
                    onClick: onClickDeploy,
                    isDisabled: true
                }],
                else:[{
                    
                        icon: `<DocumentExcelIcon />`,
                        onClick: onClickUndeploy,
                        isDisabled: true
                }]
            }
    ];
```

But this didn't work. Is it possible to achieve something like this without defining entire set of rest of the icons within if-else condition ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to use if...else... statement in React render function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40477245/is-it-possible-to-use-if-else-statement-in-react-render-function)

Comment: This may work as an alternative, but individually need to put ternary conditions. 
`icon: selectedTab:0 ? <DeploymentIcon /> : <DocumentExcelIcon />;
onClick: selectedTab:0 ? onClickDeploy : onClickUndeploy;
isDisabled: true`

Comment: @anderium  No, I am trying to add conditional object instead of an entire div element. But thank you for the suggestion. Trying to avoid rest of the icons that are common in both the cases to be defined twice.

Comment: You can't add conditions in array. You have to do it in iteration

Comment: You should perhaps think about using the array as a config file. Don't store the components/functions in there, just reference them, and call them into the main component and add them as needed. But additionally you should be using state to manage how the icons appear.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
  {
    icon: <RefreshIcon />,
    onClick: onClickRefreshRulesGrid,
    isDisabled: false
  },
  selectedTab === 0 ?
  {
     icon: `<DeploymentIcon />`,
     onClick: onClickDeploy,
     isDisabled: true
  },
   :{
     icon: `<DocumentExcelIcon />`,
     onClick: onClickUndeploy,
     isDisabled: true
  }
];
```