# Why my if statement is not working while the condition is true?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I am trying to create dynamic fields based on my selected attributes. I have 2 array objects `addAttributes` and `fakeAttributes`. fakeAttributes are the details of selected attributes. I have a dropdown select component if I pass the addAttributes it will show the data. If I select any option from my select component it will store into the `setAttributes` state.

Live code: https://codesandbox.io/s/summer-cloud-m0bvn?file=/src/App.js:1247-1678

```
 const [attributes, setAttributes] = useState([{ label: '', value: 1 }])

    const addAttributes = [
        { label: 'colors', value: 1 },
        { label: 'size', value: 2 },
    ]

    // Attributes data
     const fakeAttributes = [{
        label: 'colors',
        object: [
            { label: 'Black', value: 1 },
            { label: 'Green', value: 2 },
        ]
    },
    {
        label: 'size',
        object: [
            { label: 'M', value: 1 },
            { label: 'S', value: 2 },
        ]
    }
    ]
```

Dropdown UI. I am using npm i react-select package for the dropdown.
[image: dropdown ui]
This is my code where I am trying to filter and map those array objects if the value matches with the label it will show a text but the output is not showing also I did not get any error. The condition is matching.

```
<div className='flex flex-row gap-6'>
        <div className="basis-1/4">

            <label className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 mb-3"> Size </label>
            <Select options={addAttributes} onChange={(e: any) => setAttributes(e)} className="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"  isMulti />

        </div>
         {fakeAttributes.map((attr) => {
          attributes.filter((list) => {
            console.log(typeof attr.label,":",attr.label,typeof list.label,":",list.label);
            if (list.label === attr.label) {
              console.log("ok I am in");
              return <h2>Output</h2>;
            }
          });
        })}

    </div>
```

Can any one please help me? How can I solve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to use if...else... statement in React render function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40477245/is-it-possible-to-use-if-else-statement-in-react-render-function)

Comment: *"Why my if statement is not working while the condition is true?"* Clearly, your condition *isn't* true. You need to do the debugging to find out why not: Put a breakpoint on the `if` and, when it's hit, look at `list.label` and `attr.label` to find out why they're different. `if` and `===` **aren't broken**. If that `if` isn't working, it's because the values are different.

Comment: Separately, the way SO works, your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked.  Three reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; some sites are blocked for some users; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. You've included a bit of code in the question, but hidden most of it off-site. Instead, use Stack Snippets to do a runnable example **here, on-site**. They support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: What is the value of `list.label`? What is the value of `attr.label`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your return statement is in the scope of the filter block. So you are returning the html as the boolean of the filter method which will always be true. And then when the filtering is done, you dont do anything with the filtered items.

If you want to return the filtered item, you have to first end the filter block, then find the item and return it.

See this:

```html
import { useState } from "react";
import Select from "react-select";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [attributes, setAttributes] = useState([{ label: "", value: 1 }]);
  // Data need to break and store label info in another variable and add value dynamically
  const addAttributes = [
    { label: "colors", value: 1 },
    { label: "size", value: 2 }
  ];

  // Attributes data
  const fakeAttributes = [
    {
      label: "colors",
      object: [
        { label: "Black", value: 1 },
        { label: "Green", value: 2 }
      ]
    },
    {
      label: "size",
      object: [
        { label: "M", value: 1 },
        { label: "S", value: 2 }
      ]
    }
  ];
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="flex flex-row gap-6">
        <div className="basis-1/4">
          <label className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 mb-3">
            {" "}
            Size{" "}
          </label>
          <Select
            onChange={(e) => setAttributes(e)}
            className="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
            options={addAttributes}
            isMulti
          />
        </div>

        {fakeAttributes.map((attr) => {
          const item = attributes.filter((list) => {
            return list.label === attr.label;
          })[0];
         if (item) { 
          console.log("ok I am in");
          return <h2>Output</h2>;
        }
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```