# If statement in Jsx render based on data

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, if-statement, jsx

Whats simplest way to write a if statement in jsx when its based on data your receiving

how can i check the other code at the same time-if that makes sense? so if its not "P" then i want to make sure the other value is deffo a "L"?

code = P  so output “Walking”
code = L  so output "Running"

```
    text={
if(exercise.code = P)
{ "Walking"} 
else (exercise.code = L) 
{"Running"}}
```

Comment: ternary operator ig.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to use if...else... statement in React render function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40477245/is-it-possible-to-use-if-else-statement-in-react-render-function)

Comment: Create an object that maps each code to a string, and then just perform a lookup by code.

Comment: i have thought about that but im trying to use the simplest amount of code

Answer (score 2):

```
{
  exercise?.code === "P" ? "Walking" : exercise?.code === "L" ? "Running" 
  : null 
}
```

Here {} means you are in JS and can write if conditions. ? : is ternary operator.

Comment: is there any shorter way of writing that statement and do you have include null? or can it run without it?

Comment: you can ommit null and this is only shorter way ( simplest one ) here. Please accept the answer so that it can be closed. thanks

Comment: why the question mark after exercise

Comment: that question mark means only evaluate excercise if it exists ( re-call exercise will be null in first render of the component ( execution of syc xode ))

Comment: @kkongkk there's a shorter way, by using && operator

Answer (score 1):

```js
{ exercise.code === "P" ? "Walking" : "Running" }
```

Comment: thats was my initial  thought  but lets say if there more letters/codes= i need to be distinct....

Comment: you can still use it but change the condition the for letters/codes to make it work

Comment: let's say you have have an array of codes so, you do like
`arr.includes("somecode") ? "walk" : "Run"`

Comment: how can i check the other code at the same time-if that makes sense? so if its not "P" then i want to make sure the other value is deffo a "L"?

Answer (score 1):

Create an object to use as a mapping:

```
const codeMap = {
  C: "Crawling",
  P: "Walking",
  L: "Running"
};
```

Then you can perform a lookup in your JSX:

```
... { codeMap[excercise?.code] || "Unknown/missing code" } ...
```

That will allow you to have as many codes as you want, and the JSX will not have to be changed.

Comment: thanks, i have thought about that but im trying to use the simplest amount of code- so just really one line or two to render the text

Comment: e.g { exercise.code === "P" ? "Walking" : "Running" } but i want to validate that the other letter too if its not the one checked

Comment: @kkongkk in another comment you said that there might be several more codes. So which is it?

Comment: there will be more but i only need to point to two

Answer (score 0):

```
switch(excercise?.code){
   case 'P': return 'Walking';
   case 'L': return 'Running';
}
```

Comment: not what im looking for :(

Comment: Maybe define your question a little better. It seems like people are coming up with answers but they don't quite hit the mark. Possibly give a more thorough example of what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

this will solve your problem

```
{exercise.code == "P" && "Walking" || exercise.code == "L" && "Runing"}
```